# QVGA emulator uses wrong layout resources

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-screen-support

I'm trying to support as many android devices as I can for the my app.We have a limited number of test devices to work with, so I have used emulators for testing different screen resolution.But trying to do so found a problem that QVGA emulator uses layout-normal and drawable-hdpi folders not correct folders. I have drawable folders for each screen size & density combination (e.g. drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi, etc.).I have used an emulator of density 120 and and API level 15.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines to your `AndroidManifest.xml` -

```
<supports-screens       
 android:smallScreens="true" 
 android:normalScreens="true" 
 android:largeScreens="true" 
 android:xlargeScreens="true"
 />
```

`android:smallScreens` is necessary to support small screens in QVGA emulator, if these are absent, only the supported screen size or resolution will be available, in your case hdpi.

**EDIT:**

Try putting `android:anyDensity="true"` in the same tag.